# Функция mail возвращает false

Tags: php, email

Написал функцию, сделал условие (проходит ли условие), условие не проходит, но всё же выполняется, почему не проходит условие, а идёт в иначе?
Вот тут вызов функции и условие:

```
 if (send_mail($getEmail,'Активация вашего аккаунта',$message))
 {
    $message = lang('see_mail');
 } else {
   $message = 'Что-то не так';
 }
```

вот функция `send_mail`:

```
 /*
 ** Отправка почты **
 * whom - получатель
 * subject - Тема письма
 * text - текст
 */
 function send_mail($subject,$whom,$text){
    global $config;
    $subject=$subject;
    $header="Content-type: text/html; charset=\"windows-1251\"";
    $header.="From: <".$config['site_email'].">";
    $header.="Subject: ".$subject;
    $header.="Content-type: text/html; charset=\"windows-1251\"";
    mail($whom, $subject, $text, $header);
 }
```

Comment: А почему функция send_mail не возвращает не true не false? Функция должна же что-то возвращать чтобы Вы это проверили в условии...

Comment: @Алексей Скляр, ответ, решающий проблему, принято отмечать верным (или принимать), кликнув по галочке под рейтингом ответа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

у вас `send_mail` ничего не возвращает. Попробуйте добавить `return` в конце:

```
/*
 ** Отправка почты **
 * whom - получатель
 * subject - Тема письма
 * text - текст
 */
 function send_mail($subject,$whom,$text){
    global $config;
    $subject=$subject;
    $header="Content-type: text/html; charset=\"windows-1251\"";
    $header.="From: <".$config['site_email'].">";
    $header.="Subject: ".$subject;
    $header.="Content-type: text/html; charset=\"windows-1251\"";
    return mail($whom, $subject, $text, $header);
 }
```